# Firestore database on insert/delete document callbacks not being invoked when there is no connection

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying firestore database on Android.

This is my code that inserts a document:

```
public Observable<Post> createPost(final Post post){


        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Subscriber<? super Post> subscriber) {

                try{

                    DocumentReference documentReference = getCollection().document();

                    post.setId(documentReference.getId());
                    documentReference.set(post).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                            subscriber.onNext(post);
                            subscriber.onCompleted();

                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            subscriber.onError(e);
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        }
                    });


                }catch (Exception ex){

                    subscriber.onError(ex);

                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.getMessage(), ex);

                }

            }
        });


    }
```

The document gets inserted into the database but neither of the onSuccess nor the onFailure callbacks are invoked.

### Update 1

---

1. The issue is not consistent sometimes it works, sometimes the callbacks are invoked after an hour, sometimes after 3 hours etc..
2. This is happening when there is no internet connection.

### Update 2

1. The issue was reported [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/386) and it is closed. I am not sure how to guarantee the correctness of data created offline.

Comment: Would you mind adding more code with regards to the class hosting this method, and the class calling this method. Perhaps we can get more insight

Comment: ok, posted the whole method

Comment: Added a new answer, similar to yours, let me know what you get.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be anything wrong with your code, try perhaps the `onCompleteListener` callback. So add

```
.addOnCompleteListener((Task<Void> task) -> {
                    if(task.getException() != null) {
                        emitter.onError(task.getException());
                    }
                    if(task.isComplete()) { //try task.isSuccessful() if this is what you are looking for
                        emitter.onComplete();
                    }
                });
```

If this does not solve your issue perhaps, use an emitter like so:

```
Completable completable$ = Completable.create((CompletableEmitter emitter) -> {
    firebaseFirestore.collection(collection).document(document)
        .delete()
        .addOnSuccessListener((Void aVoid) -> emitter.onComplete())
        .addOnFailureListener((Exception e) -> emitter.onError(e))
        .addOnCompleteListener((Task<Void> task) -> {
            if(task.getException() != null) {
                emitter.onError(task.getException());
            }
            if(task.isComplete()) { //try task.isSuccessful()
                emitter.onComplete();
            }
        });
});
return completable$;
```

Comment: I tried adding ```addOnCompleteListener``` but still not working. Also I updated the question please check. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I did a simple version of your question but instead of adding a post, it adds a `User`. The concept is the same.

Here is the method to add a user. It returns an `Observable<DocumentReference>` just to reference where the user was added.

```
public  Observable<DocumentReference> insertToFirebaseFirestore$() {
    UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
    userEntity.setEmail("myemail@myemail.com");
    userEntity.setBio("I'm a cool cat!");
    userEntity.setDisplayName("KoolKat!");

//Notice here I am using an ObservableEmitter instead of Subscriber like you did
    return Observable.create((ObservableEmitter<DocumentReference> emitter) -> {
        this.firebaseFirestore.collection("tempUsers")
                .add(userEntity)
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        emitter.onError(e);
                    }
                })
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
//this gets triggered when I run
                        emitter.onNext(documentReference);
                    }
                })
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
//this also gets triggered when I run
                        emitter.onNext(task.getResult());
                    }
                });
    });

}
```

When I run this, and place breakpoints inside `onSuccess` and `onComplete`. Both of them are triggered and I can see the output.

I call the method from the Activity as follows.

```
...onCreate method
insertToFirebaseFirestore$()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io()) //observe on io thread cause I don't need it to updateUI.
        .subscribe((DocumentReference val) ->{
            Log.e("USERACTIVITY", "You have uploaded " + val.getId());
        });
```

The LogcatPrints

```
12-13 09:47:47.942 15007-15059/com.example.debug E/USERACTIVITY: You have uploaded sFBsF4ZmwGaDdxCEKuF6
12-13 09:47:57.563 15007-15059/com.example.debug E/USERACTIVITY: You have uploaded sFBsF4ZmwGaDdxCEKuF6.
```

1. From what I have see with yours, perhaps use an `emitter` within
   your `Observable.create`.
2. If that doesn't work try doing the firestore call without wrapping
   it in an observable
3. If all else, might be a connection issue, since you say it happens
   intermittently

Comment: couldnt get ```ObservableEmitter``` class. Which lib are u using for rx?

Comment: and it could not be connection issue because I have enabled offline persistency.

Comment: I think you are right the issue is happening when the user is not connected to the internet. I have enabled offline perssistency but dont know what is causing the issue.

Comment: Offline persistence is by default always enabled on Android and iOS. I am using //rxjava ` compile io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.5` . The way I get the emitter is by typing in `Observable.create(emitter->{})` 2. inside the parentheses I press `alt+enter` to expand the lambda to the receive its type. At which point it automatically locates the correct class. I believe by default if you type in a parameter within the `create()` it will assume it is of type emitter.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this with react native.

For inserts the key is to create a new document.

**example:**

```
const userRef = firebase.firestore()
                  .collection("users")
                  .doc();
userRef.set({name: someName});
```

This will create the document offline and sync when you come back online.

Further calls such as this will work offline

```
userRef.collection("Locations").add({location: "Austin,TX"});
```